# mysql compare sales/purchase in single query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

We have a proprietary sales system that we've been using for a while.
Recently we've added the "purchase" side so that we may compare average purchase/sale prices for matching products as well as see an inventory position.

In MySQL, I have 2 tables: tblPurchases and tblSalesDetail.

Each has productID, quantity, price, and freight fields (all numbers).

I want to query out per product ID:

> [product ID]  [total sum purchase quantity]  [avg purchase price] 
>   [avg purchase freight]  [total sale quantity]  [avg sale price]  [avg
>   sale freight]

My current sql statement looks like this

```
select 
    tblPurchases.productID,
    tblSalesDetail.productNo,
    sum(tblPurchases.quantity) as pQuantity,
    avg(tblPurchases.price) as pPrice,
    avg(tblPurchases.freight) as pFreight,
    sum(tblSalesDetail.quantity) as sQuantity,
    format(avg(tblSalesDetail.unitPrice),2) as sPrice,
    format(avg(tblSalesDetail.freight),2) as sFreight
from
    tblPurchases
left join tblSalesDetail
    on tblPurchases.productID=tblSalesDetail.productNo
group by tblPurchases.productID
```

but it only works properly when there are matching product ID's on both sides.
I want it to also display sales for product ID's for which there are no matching purchase product ID's.

Is that possible with a single query?

=============

## edited

the new query looks like this

```
select 
  ps.productID, 
  ps.productNo,
  sum(ps.pQuantity) as pQuantity, 
  avg(ps.pPrice) as pPrice, 
  avg(ps.pFreight) as pFreight,
  sum(sQuantity) as sQuantity, 
  avg(sPrice) as sPrice, 
  avg(sFreight) as sFreight
from (
        (select productID, 
                null as productNo,
                quantity as pQuantity, 
                price as pPrice, 
                freight as pFreight,
                NULL as sQuantity, 
                NULL as sPrice, 
                NULL as sFreight
         from tblPurchases)  

      union all

      (select null as productID, 
              productNo, 
              NULL as pQuantity,
              NULL as pPrice,
              null as pFreight,
              quantity as sQuantity, 
              unitPrice as sPrice, 
              freight as sFreight
       from tblSalesDetail
      )
     ) as ps
group by ps.productID
```

But I get 2 rows, with unmatched sales all being averaged together on one row.

[image: result set]

If I run each individual query, such as

```
select null as productID, 
                  productNo, 
                  NULL as pQuantity,
                  NULL as pPrice,
                  null as pFreight,
                  quantity as sQuantity, 
                  unitPrice as sPrice, 
                  freight as sFreight
           from tblSalesDetail
```

I get what I expect to get (about 5000 rows).

===============

## SOLVED

```
select 
*
from (
      (select   tblPurchases.productID as pProduct, 
                tblSalesDetail.productNo as sProduct,
                sum(tblPurchases.quantity) as pQuantity, 
                avg(tblPurchases.price) as pPrice, 
                avg(tblPurchases.freight) as pFreight,
                tblSalesDetail.quantity as sQuantity, 
                tblSalesDetail.unitPrice as sPrice, 
                tblSalesDetail.freight as sFreight
      from tblPurchases
      left join tblSalesDetail on tblPurchases.productID=tblSalesDetail.productNo
      group by tblPurchases.productID)   

      union all

      (select tblPurchases.productID as pProduct, 
              tblSalesDetail.productNo, 
              tblPurchases.quantity as pQuantity,
              tblPurchases.price as pPrice,
              tblPurchases.freight as pFreight,
              sum(tblSalesDetail.quantity) as sQuantity, 
              avg(tblSalesDetail.unitPrice) as sPrice, 
              avg(tblSalesDetail.freight) as sFreight
       from tblSalesDetail
       left join tblPurchases on tblPurchases.productID=tblSalesDetail.productNo
       group by tblSalesDetail.productNo)

     ) as ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` TO `tblSalesDetail`, which gives all instances of matches from both sides, and instances of purchases that do not have sales detail (not the other way around). Two options:

**Give me all sales details, but only purchases that match**

```
SELECT Purchases.productID AS productID
    ,Sales.productNo AS productNo
    ,SUM(Purchases.quantity) AS pQuantity
    ,AVG(Purchases.price) AS pPrice
    ,AVG(Purchases.freight) AS pFreight
    ,SUM(Sales.quantity) AS sQuantity
    ,FORMAT(AVG(Sales.unitPrice),2) AS sPrice
    ,FORMAT(AVG(Sales.freight),2) AS sFreight
FROM tblSalesDetail AS Sales
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPurchases AS Purchases
    ON Purchases.productID = Sales.productNo
GROUP BY Purchases.productID
```

Just switch the tables, and `tblSalesDetail` becomes the driver.

**Give me all sales details and all purchases, regardless of match**

Note: edited because MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`s.

```
SELECT productID
    ,productNo
    ,SUM(pQuantity) AS pQuantity
    ,AVG(pPrice) AS pPrice
    ,AVG(pFreight) AS pFreight
    ,SUM(sQuantity) AS sQuantity
    ,FORMAT(AVG(sPrice),2) AS sPrice
    ,FORMAT(AVG(sFreight),2) AS sFreight
FROM (
    SELECT Purchases.productID AS productID
        ,Sales.productNo AS productNo
        ,Purchases.quantity AS pQuantity
        ,Purchases.price AS pPrice
        ,Purchases.freight AS pFreight
        ,Sales.quantity AS sQuantity
        ,Sales.unitPrice AS sPrice
        ,Sales.freight AS sFreight
    FROM tblPurchases AS Purchases
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSalesDetail AS Sales
        ON Purchases.productID = Sales.productNo

    UNION

    SELECT Purchases.productID AS productID
        ,Sales.productNo AS productNo
        ,Purchases.quantity AS pQuantity
        ,Purchases.price AS pPrice
        ,Purchases.freight AS pFreight
        ,Sales.quantity AS sQuantity
        ,Sales.unitPrice AS sPrice
        ,Sales.freight AS sFreight
    FROM tblSalesDetail AS Sales
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPurchases AS Purchases
        ON Purchases.productID = Sales.productNo
) AS FullOuterJoin
GROUP BY productID
    ,productNo
```

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` (done via `UNION ALL` with two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`S, then GROUPed together) will relate matches when they exist, but provide all existing records from both tables even if one side does not match the other, or vice-versa.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me an error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join tblSalesDetail
 on tblPurchases.productID=tblSalesDetail.productNo
gr' at line 12
State: 37000; Native: 1064; Origin: [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.39-log]

Comment: ah damn, i so rarely need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` id forgotten it was one of the few ANSI syntaxes not supported by MySQL. i've updated my second example to use the `UNION` workaround.

Comment: Thank you. That's closer. It's giving me 2 rows now instead of 1. It looks like what it's doing is giving me the same line as before, plus another row that has averages and sums of all the rest of sales (that don't have a purchase match) together, instead of grouping and listing them by Sales.productNo

Comment: sorry, i was rushed in my answer and forgot to do the aggregation on the top layer rather than the subquery. i have updated my answer to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` (you could do it as a three-layer query, but only really necessary if you are processing records in the millions) and do a simpler top-layer aggregation. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need a `full outer join`, but MySQL doesn't support it.  However, you can do basically the same thing with `union all` and aggregation.  This is basically what the query looks like:

```
select ps.productID, 
       sum(pquantity) as pQuantity, avg(pPrice) as pPrice, avg(pFreight) as pFreight,
       sum(squantity) as sQuantity, avg(sPrice) as sPrice, avg(sFreight) as sFreight
from ((select productid,
              quantity as pQuantity, price as pPrice, freight as pFreight,
              NULL as sQuantity, NULL as sPrice, NULL as sfreight
       from tblPurchases
      ) union all
      (select productno, NULL as pQuantity
              quantity as sQuantity, price as sPrice, freight as sFreight,
       from tblSalesDetail
      )
     ) ps
group by ps.productID;
```

Comment: Thank you.
Well, that doesn't err, but I only get 2 rows. It looks like it is putting (averaging/summing) all of the unmatched sales together on one row. If I run the 2 sql statements that we are attempting to UNION separately, they work as expected....

Comment: Oh, I see.  You have different keys on the two tables, a `productid` on one and a `productno` on the other.  The above fixes this.

Comment: yes the 2 fields are the same thing they should of been named the same but I inherited that. Thanks!